# C# console close after input but keep code running

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I have developed a FileSystemWatcher using C#.  The program will wait for a new file to come out every two hours, then send an email containing information that is read from the file.  The issue is that I need a username and password for the email server to authenticate.  I do not want to hard code and do not want to store username and password encrypted, as the credentials may change.  I would like to be able to enter a username and password in the console at start up of the program, have the server authenticate, and if the credentials are good, the console will close and the filesystemwatcher will keep running.  I cannot find anywhere how to simply "Close" the console but the rest of the code keep running.  I originally thought this would just be a windows application with no console, but with the username and password issue, I would like the console only in the very beginning for the user input.  Thanks! I am an amatuer not a professional developer.

Comment: It sounds like a candidate for a Windows Service, which you can run as a specific user. When the credentials change, you need to just restart the service with the new credentials.

Comment: You cannot exit your program and keep it running at the same time. Why not create a simple form for that authentication?

Comment: I ended up making a simple win form for it. Works like a charm!  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction dymanoid.

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = textBox1.Text.Trim();
            string password = textBox2.Text.Trim();

            this.Close();

            Program.Run(username, password);
        }

this was my first post so not sure how to post the code to show up readable.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set up a windows task scheduler task that would run your app? Make the app do whatever it needs to and rely on a scheduler to launch it from time to time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page

You can even create a task from the app itself. Take a look at this nuget package.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/